# Want Gnome 3.28.2 shell theme CSS documentation

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

In pursuit of making some changes I accidentally deleted multiple lines in the Gnome theme CSS file. Is there any way to go back to the original state or replace another default CSS file with that one?

Comment: are you able to log on to desktop? or you still waiting with open document?

Comment: do you know the path of the css file you opened?

Comment: do not replace the file. instead replace the entire content from the native file into your corrupted file. (some lines you deleted that file)

Comment: I used the following command to access it. sudo gedit/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css

Comment: Ok.. then again open the same document, delete all content...copy the content from the file in answer and paste it..